# How to implement tree (touch graph) in android?

Tags: android

Please have a look at example - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu2uVo3sxCg&feature=player_embedded.

Is there any library to implement something similar (the tree) with android? If not, then is there any example in any other language I can look into?

Upd. Can I use http://sourceforge.net/projects/touchgraph/files/GraphLayout/?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be the best solution, but take a look at this: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/ and the developers site: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/

Something like that could pretty easily be accomplished with this library. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not up to date for you but for others who are looking for a library to visualize and interact with graph structures.

https://github.com/oss-bandb/GraphView